# invalid attempt to access a field before calling read() (also after read is called)

Tags: c#, mysql

Okay... so i'm trying to make this fun minigame for my application.. I've used the code before but it won't work on my other file, it just gives me "invalid attempt to access a field before calling read()".

```
        con.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from users WHERE id='" + lblMainId.Text + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MySqlDataReader mdr;
        mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (mdr.Read())
        {
            cf.setMoney = Math.Round(mdr.GetDouble("money"), 2).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failure - Please try again!");
        }

        con.Close();
```

**EDIT:**
Found out that i made lblMainId.Text = "" earlier in my code.. Therefore it tried to select * from ""....

My bad, but thanks for the answers anyway.. Hope someone else can use them :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

line. I'm not sure of it's effect on the call

```
cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

but it's definitely not needed.

Comment: Also, don't call Read() without checking mdr.HasRows. Attempting to read when zero rows were returned will throw an exception, too.  Put all of those objects in using blocks or dispose of them manually, as well. Another red flag: don't store money as a floating point number. Store it as a DECIMAL type.